# CSS Hover attribute on sub-element rather than entire element

Tags: css, hover, element

Hopefully this makes sense - my html is as follows

html

```
<a href="#" class="someclass">An <span class="sub">Interesting</span> Link</a>
```

where the css is simply color information. What I'd like to do is to make it so when you mouseover the link as a whole only the "sub" information is affected by the hover attribute. While this would be easy enough to do in javascript I was curious as to whether or not css allowed for this behavior. If I were to try to write this it would probably look like

```
a:hover{
    .sub{color:newcolor};
}
```

however I've never seen anything like that and obviously it doesn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
a:hover .sub { color: newcolor }
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
a:hover .sub { color: #f00; }
```

If you need to apply it only to that specific class:

```
a.someclass:hover .sub { color: #f00; }
```